# Python, list.remove() does not work right

Tags: python, list

Hello I am trying to remove first and last 2 element of my list.
My list is: `['12','30','22','06','27','13','23','16','14','20','09','29','23']`

and this is the code I am using:

```
dList.remove(dList[0])
dList.remove(dList[-1])
dList.remove(dList[-1])
```

It works right too many other list but in this list it returns:

```
['30', '22', '06', '27', '13', '16', '14', '20', '09', '29']
```

Instead of;

```
['30', '22', '06', '27', '13', '23', '16', '14', '20', '09',]
```

I noticed the last element is '23' and both '23' be removed but I don't know how to fix it. It should be work right because I remove first element, and last element, and last element again. I didn't use:

```
a = dList[0]
dList.remove(a)
a = dList[-1]
dList.remove(a)
a = dList[-1]
dList.remove(a)
```

Comment: why not trying ```dList = dList[1:-2]```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The remove() method removes the first matching element (which is passed as an argument) from the list.

You have `23` repeated twice.

If you want to remove index you can use `del` in your example.it would be:

`del dList[-1]`

Answer (score 0):

Why not using `pop` to pop out the last element of the list?

```py
last_element = dList.pop()
semilast_element = dList.pop()
```

You can even put the index of the element you want to pop

```py
first_element = dList.pop(0)
second_element = dList.pop(0)
```

Always refer to the original [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

Answer (score 0):

With:

```
dList = ['12','30','22','06','27','13','23','16','14','20','09','29','23']
```

...you could construct a new list with a slice (as previously suggested) like this:

dList = dList[1:-2]

...or you can do it *in situ* using *pop()* as follows:

```
dList.pop(0)
dList.pop()
dList.pop()
```